# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ is converges uniformly if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges and $|f_n(x)|<a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I am asked to prove the following:

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ be a series of continuous functions in an set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^p$. If there exists constants $a_n > 0,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, and $|f_n(x)|<a_n$ for $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\forall x \in K$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ is converges uniformly in $K$.

My approach:

If $|f_n(x)|<a_n$ and because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f_n|$ converges as well. This makes $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ absolutely convergent. But how can I show that this convergence is uniform and not pointwise?

Comment: Have a look at: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have established $\sum_{n \geqslant 1} f_n$ converges;  call its limit $ F(x) $.  Then for $ x \in K $, use the convergence of $\sum_{n \geqslant 1} a_n $ to choose $N$ and calculate a bound for 
$$\left|  F(x) - \sum_{n = 1}^{N} f_n(x) \right|. $$
You should find the same bound works for all $x$.